# WYSIWYG in CKEditor - how to disable/add modules

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ckeditor, wysiwyg

i am using  CKEDITOR.replaceAll('wysiwyg');  to replace form text areas to wysiwyg on my website, but i would like to disable some modules, like italic font, links ... how to do it please? I could not found any examples.

Comment: it has a great manual, just use it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to customize CK-Editor's tools menu?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813359/how-to-customize-ck-editors-tools-menu)

Comment: ^^ unlikely he is using that version, its rather old

Answer (score 0):

to disable the modules,add the below code in config.js file of CKEditor,

```
config.removeButtons = 'Underline,JustifyCenter';
```